# .net Serialization/Deserialization of complex types

Tags: .net, vb.net, serialization, deserialization, binaryformatter

I'm trying to deserialize an object which was serialized with an earlier version of the same assembly (strong named), so only the version number is different (same application, same assembly, class hasn't changed). I use the BinaryFormatter for serializing/deserializing.
I created a custom SerializationBinder which takes care of the version number problem. This works fine for simple classes. 
Now the problem is, my class has a dataset member with objects of another class in it. This is where the deserialization fails. Is there any possibility, I can deserialize these objects at all?
We have lots of customers who have serialized objects in their databases, so it should be possible to deserialize them with newer versions too without changing the serialization concept in general. Deserialization worked for all the years but now we had to change the version number of our assemblies which causes the problem.

The code is too complex to post the whole thing, I narrowed it down to a simple example which throws the same exception when it comes to deserializing.

ClassA - Class to serialize, 
ClassB - Objects of ClassB in ClassA.dataset

```
<Serializable()> _
Public Class ClassA
    Public ID As Int64
    Public data As DataSet
End Class

<Serializable()> _
Public Class ClassB
    Public str As String = ""
    Public num As Int64
End Class
```

Initializing of the object to serialize and method calls for serializing and deserializing

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary
Imports serialisierung

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub btnSerialize_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSerialize.Click

        Try

            Dim myClassA As ClassA = Nothing
            myClassA = New ClassA()

            myClassA.data = New DataSet
            myClassA.data.Tables.Add("ClassA")
            myClassA.data.Tables(0).Columns.Add("ClassB", GetType(ClassB))

            Dim myClassB As New ClassB()
            myClassB.str = "some String"
            myClassB.num = 3

            Dim drClassB As DataRow
            drClassB = myClassA.data.Tables(0).NewRow
            drClassB.Item("ClassB") = myClassB
            myClassA.data.Tables(0).Rows.Add(drClassB)

            Dim ser As New CSerializer
            ser.serialize(myClassA)

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
      End Sub

    Private Sub btnDeserialize_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDeserialize.Click

        Try

            Dim ser As New CSerializer
            Dim obj As ClassA = ser.deserialize()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
      End Sub
End Class
```

Serialization class

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary

Public Class CSerializer

    Private filename As String = "C:\bin.txt"

    Public Sub serialize(obj As ClassA)

        Try

            If (File.Exists(filename)) Then
                File.Delete(filename)
            End If

            Dim stream As FileStream = File.Create(filename)
            Dim formatter As New BinaryFormatter()

            formatter.Serialize(stream, obj)
            stream.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try

    End Sub

    Public Function deserialize() As ClassA

        Dim obj As ClassA

        Try

            Dim stream As FileStream
            Dim formatter As New BinaryFormatter()
            formatter.Binder = New AllowAllAssemblyVersionsDeserializationBinder()
            formatter.AssemblyFormat = Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.FormatterAssemblyStyle.Simple
            stream = File.OpenRead(filename)

            obj = formatter.Deserialize(stream)
            stream.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
            Dim str As String = ex.Message
        End Try

        Return obj

    End Function


End Class

NotInheritable Class AllowAllAssemblyVersionsDeserializationBinder
    Inherits System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationBinder

    Public Overrides Function BindToType(ByVal AssemblyName As String, ByVal TypeName As String) As System.Type

        Dim myType As Type = GetType(ClassA)
        Dim beginTypeName As String
        Dim TypeToDeserialize As Type

        If TypeName.StartsWith("System.") Then
            If TypeName.IndexOf("[") >= 0 Then
                beginTypeName = TypeName.Substring(0, TypeName.IndexOf("["))
                TypeName = String.Format("{0}[[{1}]]", beginTypeName, myType.AssemblyQualifiedName)
            End If
        Else
            AssemblyName = myType.Assembly.ToString
            TypeName = myType.FullName
        End If

        TypeToDeserialize = Type.GetType(String.Format("{0}, {1}", TypeName, AssemblyName))

        Return TypeToDeserialize

    End Function

End Class
```

The serialized object looks like that (saved as a file in the example, our application stores the serialized object in a database.

```
    ÿÿÿÿ          Qserialisierung, Version=1.2.3.4, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e3eee34ac29f76ba   NSystem.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089   serialisierung.ClassA   IDdata    System.Data.DataSet                        System.Data.DataSet   DataSet.RemotingVersion   XmlSchemaXmlDiffGramSystem.Version          ©<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
  <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="ClassA">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="ClassB" msdata:DataType="serialisierung.ClassB, serialisierung, Version=1.2.3.4, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e3eee34ac29f76ba" type="xs:anyType" msdata:targetNamespace="" minOccurs="0" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>   •<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1"><NewDataSet><ClassA diffgr:id="ClassA1" msdata:rowOrder="0" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted"><ClassB xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><str>some String</str><num>3</num></ClassB></ClassA></NewDataSet></diffgr:diffgram>   System.Version   _Major_Minor_Build   _Revision           ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ
```